# setting up multi-mon windows + mac

Tags: windows, mac, multiple-monitors

Ok this is a stretch, but I know of some Windows only software that does this so curious if there is something that does it on the mac too.

I have 2 monitors and 2 development machines - a PC and a Mac Mini. I want to be able to view/control both concurrently (one on each monitor). The Mac only has DisplayPort (w/ DVI adapter) out, the PC has both and my monitors have both.

Any suggestions on how I can do it? A solution involving KVM or software (VNC/remoting) is OK...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) setup.  Whichever computer you leave on more often or currently have your keyboard/mouse hooked to should become the 'server'.  I've had really good luck with this software and highly recommend it.

If that doesn't work, then I suppose you could use [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/) on your mac to RDP to your windows machine.  It works pretty slick as well, but wont have quite the 'cool-factor' that synergy does :)